# Electronic Circuits - Calculate voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

How do I calculate the voltage v1 using KCL?

[image]

I don't understand how I should express the current I3 to get the equation right.

[image]

I already watched this video but I don't know what to do when there are two resistors. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMnFC63m1fQ